# Mutex not locking and using not releasing file handle

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, mutex

I am having problems getting a file handle to close properly. I have tried to use an additional `Mutex` to ensure only one thread has access to this file at a time.

As far as I understand it the `Using` construct should ensure that the file handle is released properly, and the `Mutex` should ensure that this code can only run in 1 thread at a time.

The error occurs when the logger is called multiple times in rapid succession.

The gethashcode was an attempt to verify that the mutex instance is the same.

Error Message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   The process cannot access the file '****\LOG.log' because it is being used by another process.

Source:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Threading

Public NotInheritable Class FileLogger
    Private Shared ReadOnly _instance As New Lazy(Of FileLogger)(Function() New FileLogger(), System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication)
    Public LOG_LEVEL As Integer = 4
    Public LEVELS As New Dictionary(Of Double, String)
    Private Shared strFile As String = "LOG.log"
    Public Shared FileLoc As New Mutex()

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property getLogger() As FileLogger
        Get
            Return _instance.Value
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub New()
        Dim strFile As String = "yourfile.log"
        LEVELS.Add(0, "FATAL   ")
        LEVELS.Add(1, "CRITICAL")
        LEVELS.Add(2, "ERROR   ")
        LEVELS.Add(3, "INFO    ")
        LEVELS.Add(4, "DEBUG   ")
        LEVELS.Add(2.5, "WARNING ")
    End Sub

    Public Sub writeEntry(ByVal message As String, ByVal level As Double)
        If level <= LOG_LEVEL Then
            Dim log_str As String = String.Format("{0} - in: {3} - {1}: {2}", DateTime.Now.ToString, LEVELS(level), message, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)

            Console.WriteLine(log_str)
            If level < 3 Then ' warning or greater write to file else just console
                Console.WriteLine(FileLoc.GetHashCode())
                FileLoc.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite)
                Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(strFile, True) '<-- Debugger points to this line
                    sw.WriteLine(log_str)
                End Using
                FileLoc.ReleaseMutex()
            End If

            If level <= 2 Then 'if error or greater send email
                FileLoc.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite)
                Dim mail As New MailMessage
                mail.To.Add("email")
                mail.From = New MailAddress("email")
                mail.Subject = "Error on MC Server (SERVERNAME)"
                mail.Body = log_str
                mail.IsBodyHtml = True
                mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(strFile))
                Dim smtp As New SmtpClient
                smtp.Host = "IPADDR"
                smtp.Send(mail)
                FileLoc.ReleaseMutex()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub       
End Class
```

Comment: I would suggest using a simple [`SyncLock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/synclock-statement) statement, rather than a `Mutex` to protect the file access.

Comment: The mutex would normally be enough.  But doesn't do anything to avoid the failure mode described in the exception message, it *could* be "another process".  Seeing this happen when rapidly writing usually points at anti-malware being anti.  The only truly reliable way to avoid it is by not closing the file.  The way logger libraries do it.  They also use FileShare.Read so that other programs can still read the log file.  Recommended.

Answer (score 0):

The email section was not closing the file correctly. wrapping this in a using construct fixed the issue.
I also ended up implementing the `SyncLock` construct around the entire operation.

as some of the comments have pointed out the mutex may or may not have been doing what it was supposed to, but the file handle was still open from the attachment operation.

```
Public Sub writeEntry(ByVal message As String, ByVal level As Double)
        SyncLock FileLoc

            If level <= LOG_LEVEL Then
                Dim log_str As String = String.Format("{0} - in: {3} - {1}: {2}", DateTime.Now.ToString, LEVELS(level), message, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)

                Console.WriteLine(log_str)
                If level < 3 Then ' warning or greater write to file else just console
                    Console.WriteLine(FileLoc.GetHashCode())
                    Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(strFile, True)
                        sw.WriteLine(log_str)
                    End Using

                End If

                If level <= 2 Then 'if error or greater send email
                    Using at As Attachment = New Attachment(strFile)
                        Dim mail As New MailMessage
                        mail.To.Add("email")
                        mail.From = New MailAddress("email")
                        mail.Subject = "Error on MC Server (servername)"
                        mail.Body = log_str
                        mail.IsBodyHtml = True

                        mail.Attachments.Add(at)


                        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient
                        smtp.Host = "IPADDR"
                        smtp.Send(mail)
                    End Using


                End If
            End If
        End SyncLock

    End Sub
```